# Elements of eigenvectors of Laplacian matrix of complete graph

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

Assume we have a complete graph with $N$ nodes. If we show the Laplacian graph with $L$, we know that one eigenvalue of $L$ is equal to zero and all the others are equal to $N$, so we have $N-1$ eigenvalues equal to $N$.

My question is about elements of each eigenvector related to these eigenvalues. Can we say what the eigenvectors are without calculating them and their elements? Actually we have $N$ eigenvectors which the first one has the same elements equal to $\sqrt \frac{1}{N}$. Can we say anything about elements of other $N-1$ eigenvectors?

Comment: Recall that $L=NI_n-J$, $J$ being the matrix with ones everywhere. So an eigendecomposition for $J$ gives you an eigendecomposition for $L$.

Comment: Yes, you're exactly right. But how? I want to know for example what is the $j$-th element of $i$-th eigenvector. Is there any way for that?

Comment: You don’t have a well-defined ordering on your eigenvectors. You don’t even have $(N-1)$ canonical eigenvectors associated with the eigenvalue $N$, just a $(N-1)$-dimensional subspace which is the kernel of $J$. Any orthonormal basis of it will work.

Comment: So you say that every set of $(N-1)$ orthogonal basis is enough for complete graph to be determined and it's not unique?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I tested it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: A quibble: you could just as well have said that the “first” eigenvector has all elements equal to $1$. Any nonzero scalar multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector with the same eigenvalue. Although unit eigenvectors can be convenient, there’s no particular need to normalize.

Comment: Second, _any_ basis of the orthogonal complement of the null space is a set of linearly-independent eigenvectors with eigenvalue $N$. There’s no a priori reason to restrict yourself to orthonormal bases.

Comment: @amd thanks a lot :)